# SIGSEGV crash with Firebase MLKit barcode scanner

Tags: android, firebase, segmentation-fault, firebase-mlkit

I recently ran into a problem with my application: a weird crash happens when scanning QR codes coming from a particular website.

Anything generated by https://businesscards.tec-it.com/it causes a SIGSEGV crash with the following line in the logcat:

```
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x0 in tid 19717
(FirebaseMLHandl), pid 19583 (is.qrsync.debug)
```

I am using Firebase ML Kit version 16.0.0 and it works fine with, so far, any other QR code generator.

Is this a known issue? How can I investigate this further?

Thanks

Comment: this seems to be a potential bug. You can submit it to Firebase's team through their support form: https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/

Comment: Thanks, I submitted a bug report. I'll update the post with the new info ASAP.

Comment: @EmilioSchepis did you managed to solve this? In https://github.com/facundomedica/fast_qr_reader_view we are looking for an answer to this, feel free to jump into the issues!

Comment: Hi! Unfortunately I did not manage to solve it. My bug report (filed July 19) is still in  the "investigating" phase. I'm afraid it fell through the cracks. I'll file it again and update the post.